# How do I avoid using the mouse when extracting to field in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When I press Alt+Cmd+F to extract a piece of code to a field, I'd like it to be final and initialised in the field declaration, but I have to use the mouse to click on the dropdown in the pop-up. How can I do this without using the mouse?

[image: annoying popup]

Comment: Try pressing alt+cmd+f twice, which will open separate dialog where you can tab through the individual options.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> twice, which will show separate dialog in which you can tab through the individual options using the keyboard.
[image]